# d3.js treemap with 10,000 nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, orientation, treemap

js treemap that updates and re-renders when I receive new data. I have built on a data set of 50 elements and it works great. However, I am trying to run the same code on a much larger dataset 10,000 elements. And it seems to be unable to render the graphic, does anybody know of any examples of d3.js working on large data sets, or does anybody have any suggestions?

Also, when I do graph the maps, sometimes they shift position, and it seems like the orientation of the elements is messed up because they move outside the chart or overlap with another element, leaving whitespace in the throughout the graph, but after re-rendering the graph usually corrects itself, and then messes up again. I think the problem comes about because the graph is resizing itself with regards to absolute positions, but rects in certain positions from the previous render are messing things up. Any clue how to stop this intermediate phase of having a messed up graph before being able to re-render? Thanks.

This is the code I use to initially draw the d3 regraph.

```
function drawTreeMap(array1,array2, colorArray)
{
  console.log("got to drawing"); 
  var cellMargin=5;
  this.marginTree = {top:20, right:20, bottom:20, left:20};
  var coloring = d3.scale.linear()
          .range(['lightblue', 'green']) // or use hex values
          .domain([this.getMinOfThisArray(colorArray), this.getMaxOfThisArray(colorArray)]);
  this.nestedJson = this.createObj(array1, array2, colorArray);
      this.w = 1700 - 80,
      this.h = 980 - 180,
      this.x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, this.w]),
      this.y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, this.h]),

      this.root,
      this.node;


      this.treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
          .round(false)
          .size([this.w, this.h])
          .sticky(true)
          .padding([this.marginTree.bottom, this.marginTree.right, this.marginTree.top, this.marginTree.left])
          .sort(function(a,b) {
                return a.value - b.value;
            })
          .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

      this.svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")

          .attr("class", "chart")
          .style("position", "relative")
          .style("width", (this.w) + "px")
          .style("height", (this.h ) + "px")
          .style("left", this.marginTree.left +"px")
          .style("top", this.marginTree.top + "px")
        .append("svg:svg")
          .attr("width", this.w)
          .attr("height", this.h)
        .append("svg:g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");


        this.node = this.root = this.nestedJson;



        var nodes = this.treemap.nodes(this.root)
            .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

        this.tip = d3.tip()
              .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
              .html(function(d) {
                return "<span style='color:white'>" + (d.name+",\n "+d.size) + "</span>";
              })
        this.svg.call(this.tip);

        var cell = this.svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "cell")
            .call(this.position)
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
            .on("click", function(d) { return this.zoom(this.node == d.parent ? this.root : d.parent); });

        var borderPath = this.svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "border")
            .attr("x", this.marginTree.left)
            .attr("y", this.marginTree.top)
            .attr("height", this.h - this.marginTree.top - this.marginTree.bottom )
            .attr("width", this.w - this.marginTree.left - this.marginTree.right)
            .style("stroke", 'darkgrey')
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke-width", '3px');


        cell.append("svg:rect")
            .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "rect-" + (i+1); })
            .attr("class","highlighting2 cell-rects")
                .attr("title", function(d) {return (d.name+", "+d.size);})
                .attr("data-original-title", function(d) {return (d.name+",\n "+d.size);})
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx ; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy ; })
          .on('mouseover', this.tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', this.tip.hide)
          .style("fill", function(d) {return coloring(d.color);});


        cell.append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "treemap-text nameTexts") 
            .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "name-" + (i+1); })
            .attr("x", cellMargin)  
            .attr("y", function(d) {  return parseInt($('.treemap-text').css('font-size'))+cellMargin; })
          .text(function(d) {return (d.name);});

       cell.append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "treemap-text sizeTexts") 
            .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "size-" + (i+1); })  
            .attr("x", cellMargin)  
            .attr("y", function(d) {  return 2*parseInt($('.treemap-text').css('font-size'))+2*cellMargin; })
            .text(function(d) {return (d.size);});

       // d3.selectAll("svg:rect")
       //    .style("stroke-width", 2)
       //    .style("stroke", function(d){ return this.LightenDarkenColor(coloring(d.color), -5);});



          this.treeMapping = true;
        $(document).ready(function(){

            for (var i =1 ; i<graphObj.rc.positions[graphObj.currentVpName].SetSize; i++){
                var obj = "rect-"+i;
                var size = "size-"+i;
                var name = "name-"+i;
                graphObj.formatNumbers(size);
                graphObj.placeTextWithEllipsis(obj, size);
                graphObj.placeTextWithEllipsis(obj, name);

                }
          d3.selectAll(".nameTexts")
          .style("fill", "#333333");
         d3.selectAll(".sizeTexts")
          .style("fill","#383838");

         });
}
```

This is the file I use to re-render the treemap when I receive new data.

```
function redrawGraph(array1, array2, colorArray)
{   

   this.nestedJson = this.createObj(array1, array2, colorArray);
  var coloring = d3.scale.linear()
          .range(['lightblue', 'green']) // or use hex values
          .domain([this.getMinOfThisArray(colorArray), this.getMaxOfThisArray(colorArray)]);
   var cellMargin = 5;

  this.svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")

  this.treemap
    .mode("squarify")
    .round(false)
    .size([this.w,this.h])
    .sticky(true)
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });


  // Draw the graph


  this.node = this.root = this.nestedJson;

  var nodes = this.treemap.nodes(this.root)
              .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });



  var rect = d3.select("#body").selectAll(".cell-rects")
        .data(nodes);

  rect.exit().remove();

  rect.enter().append("rect");

  rect
    .transition()
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx ; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy ; })
        .attr("title", function(d) {return (d.name+", "+d.size);})
        .attr("data-original-title", function(d) {return (d.name+",\n "+d.size);})
    .style("fill", function(d) { return coloring(d.color)})
    .call(this.position);

  var text = d3.select("#body").selectAll(".nameTexts")
        .data(nodes);


  text.exit().remove();

  text.enter().append("text");

  text
    .attr("class", "treemap-text nameTexts")
    .attr("x", cellMargin)  
    .attr("y", function(d) {  return parseInt($('.treemap-text').css('font-size'))+cellMargin; })
    .text(function(d) { return (d.name); });


  var text2 = d3.select("#body").selectAll(".sizeTexts")
        .data(nodes);

  text2.exit().remove();

  text2.enter().append("text");

  text2
    .attr("class", "treemap-text sizeTexts")
    .attr("x", cellMargin)  
    .attr("y", function(d) {  return 2*parseInt($('.treemap-text').css('font-size'))+2*cellMargin; })
    .text(function(d) { return (d.size); });

  var cell = this.svg.selectAll("g")
    cell.append("svg:rect")
    cell.append("svg:text");

  // var border = this.svg.append("rect")
  //   .attr("x", this.marginTree.left)
  //   .attr("y", this.marginTree.top)
  //   .attr("height", this.h - this.marginTree.top - this.marginTree.bottom )
  //   .attr("width", this.w - this.marginTree.left - this.marginTree.right)
  //   .style("stroke", 'darkgrey')
  //   .style("fill", "none")
  //   .style("stroke-width", '3px');


    // d3.select(window).on("click", function() { 
    //   this.zoom(this.root); });

    // d3.select("select").on("change", function() 
    // {
    //   this.treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? this.size : this.count).nodes(this.root);
    //   this.zoom(this.node);
    // });
    d3.selectAll(".nameTexts")
      .style("fill", "#333333");
   d3.selectAll(".sizeTexts")
    .style("fill","#383838");

    $(document).ready(function(){

      for (var i =1 ; i<graphObj.rc.positions[graphObj.currentVpName].SetSize; i++){
          var obj = "rect-"+i;
          var size = "size-"+i;
          var name = "name-"+i;
          graphObj.formatNumbers(size);
          graphObj.placeTextWithEllipsis(obj, size);
          graphObj.placeTextWithEllipsis(obj, name); 
          }
     });
```

}

```
 rdaGraph.prototype.position = function()
 {
    this.style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
      .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
      .style("width", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px"; })
      .style("height", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px"; });
 }
```

Also by white space I mean this.

Image is linked here. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTLk6.png][1]

Comment: 1) We'd like to see some code; 2) Don't display 10000 nodes, instead reduce your data to humanly-perceptible size.

Comment: Thanks, I have attached my code. When displaying 500 nodes, I have the orientation problems, but with 25 nodes everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could stream the data to D3, check out [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) post that shows realtime streaming of data to a graph.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think the bigger problem is the rendering issue, I attached the image above, have any of you seen anything similar?